# Binomial Expansion: precalculus

Tags: binomial-theorem

In the expansion  $(1 +px)(1 +qx)^4$ in ascending powers of $x$ , the coefficient of the $x$ term is $-5$ and there is no $x^2$ term. Find the value of $p$ and $q$.

My attempted answer

1) I expanded the second bracket $(1+qx)^4 $

2) I multiplied my answer with the second bracket

3) I grouped the common $x$ terms together

The problem is that the question tells you that there is no $x^2$ term, how do I work with what I am given in the question ?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: After finding expressions of these coefficients in $p$ and $q$ you have two equalities, allowing you to find $p,q$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Using the binomial theorem and expanding the product, the coefficient of $x$ is $p+{4\choose 1} q$ and the coefficient of $x^2$ is ${4\choose 1} qp+{4\choose 2}q^2$.

Now you just need to compare coefficients.

Remark: "there is no $x^2$ term" is another way to say "the coefficient of $x^2$ is $0$"